# Fullcalendar: How to remove event

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Thanks to another post here on StackOverflow, I added some code to my select: method that prevents users from adding an event on a date prior to NOW.

The downside is that when they click on the empty time slot, and the system then complains (an alert message), the attempted event remains.  How do I get rid of it?  Thanks!

Update:  Here's my code:

```
    select: function(start, end, jsEvent) {

        var check = start._d.toJSON().slice(0,10),
            today = new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10),
            m = moment(),
            url = "[redacted]",
            result = {};
            title = "Class",
            eventData = {
                title: title,
                start: start,
                end: start.clone().add(2, 'hour'),
                durationEditable: false,
                instructorid: 123,
                locationid: 234
            };


        if(check < today) {
            alert("Cannot create an event before today.");

            $("#calendar").fullCalendar('removeEvents', function(eventObject) {
                return true;
            });

        } else {

            $.ajax({ type: "post", url: url, data: JSON.stringify(eventData), dataType: 'JSON', contentType: "application/json", success: function(result) {

                if ( result.SUCCESS == true ) {
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true);
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');

                } else {

                    alert(result.MESSAGE);
                }

            }});
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show some code ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you're using FullCalendar V2, you need to use the [removeEvents method](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/removeEvents/).

You can use it to delete events with a certain ID by calling it in this way:

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar('removeEvents', 123); //replace 123 with reference to a real ID
```

If you want to use your own function that decides whether or not an event get's removed, you can call it this way:

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar('removeEvents', function(eventObject) {
    //return true if the event 'eventObject' needs to be removed, return false if it doesn't
});
```

Comment: How do I get the eventid to remove?  This is in the select: method, where my params are start, end, and jsEvent according to the docs.

Comment: As a result of calling `removeEvents`, FullCalendar will call your callback for every event object there is, with the current event object as a parameter, which I called `eventObject`. If you put `console.log(eventObject);` in the callback function instead of my comment, you'll be able to see its contents. You can return true or false depending on certain checks on the contents of `eventObject` (true will delete, false will keep).

Comment: Thanks... I tried the one with the callback and it doesn't do anything.  No error, but graphical event bubble remains on the page.  Do I need to do something separate to remove it?

Comment: Update... actually it does work, if after clicking OK on the alert box, you then click someplace else on the page.  Then the bubble disappears.

Answer (score 2):

FullCalendar has a `removeEvent` method that uses an `id` when you create the event.

Example Full Calendar v1:

```
var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({ ... stuff ... });
    calendar.fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', {id:123, stuff:'stuff'});
    // ... other calendar things here...
    calendar.fullCalendar( 'removeEvent', 123);
```

[Reference API v1](http://fullcalendar.io/docs1/removed/removeEvent/)

Example FullCalendar v2:

```
var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({ ... stuff ... });
    calendar.fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', {id:123, stuff:'stuff'});
    // ... other calendar things here...
    calendar.fullCalendar( 'removeEvents', [123]);
```

[Reference API v2](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/removeEvents/)

Comment: That's for fullCalendar v1, that method doesn't exist anymore in fullCalendar v2.

Answer (score 2):

Version 4.3

```
        calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
                plugins : [ 'interaction', 'dayGrid', 'list' ],
                header : {
                    left : 'prev,next today',
                    center : 'title',
                    right : 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,list'
                },
                editable : true,
                droppable : true, 
                eventReceive : function(info) {
                    alert(info.event.title);

                },
                eventDrop : function(info) {
                    alert(info.event.title + " was dropped on "
                            + info.event.start.toISOString());

                    if (!confirm("Are you sure about this change?")) {
                        info.revert();
                    }
                },
                eventClick : function(info) {
                     //delete event from calender
                    info.event.remove();

                }

            });

            calendar.render();
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Full calendar version 4

How to remove event from calendar:

```
<div id="calendar"></div>

<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
      events: [
        {
          id: '505',
          title: 'My Event',
          start: '2010-01-01',
          url: 'http://google.com/'
        }
        // other events here
      ],
      eventClick: function(info) {
        info.jsEvent.preventDefault(); // don't let the browser navigate

        if (info.event.id) {
            var event = calendar.getEventById(info.event.id);
            event.remove();
        }
      }
    });
});
</script>
```

This worked for me. I hope, this will also help you. Thanks for asking this question.